# CSS Diagonal Lines with filled space

Tags: css

I'm building a website and I would like to have a bar of navigation links that is a solid color and then off to the far right I would like to have a diagonal line to come up a little bit over the bar of links and then have a limited height(level off) and have a search box in the raised area above the navigation links.

How would I go about 1 creating a diagonal line in css and then is it possible to fill the space with a solid color under one side of the said diagonal line?

Comment: First, you should show us a picture of what you'd like us to help you create; and, second, you should post what you've already tried, and how it didn't work? Also: show us the `(x)html` you're working with.

Comment: I will get a pcture of what I'm trying to do. I know I can create diagonal lines with some work, but I really want to know is can I fill the space under the under the line with a solid color. [I was looking at this for diagonal lines and according to many sites borders are the way to make it happen.](http://erezsh.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/drawing-diagonal-lines-with-css/) It is more so the filling below one side of the line I'm wondering how to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Diagonal line with a solid color under the line...

***html***

```
<div class="uguu"></div>
```

***css***

```
.uguu {
    line-height:0;
    width:0;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:100px solid green;
}
```

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83Wyy/**

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I'll work on line smoothing and such, but that is a much better method than the one I was previously trying.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about **1 creating a diagonal line in css** and then is it possible to **fill the space with a solid color under one side of the said diagonal line**?

Simple solution : Does not exist.

Complex solution : With lots of CSS, absolute positionning, not caring about IE (use of `-moz-transform: rotate(45deg)`), [you can draw silly stuff](http://jsfiddle.net/JEMca/1/).

[See what some people can end up doing...](http://kristriplett.com/tinker/vader.html)

Personnaly, I'd go with @a solutions : use a background image.

If you really want to "draw", go with SGV, [see this article](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/create-cross-browser-vector-graphics/) for an example, using the dojo js framework.

Answer (score 0):

To have a diagonal line in the background, you need to create a background image.

You can use this site to create a striped diagonal background: http://www.stripegenerator.com/

For what you're doing, I'd recommend having 2 separate striped backgrounds.